# Programmatically set the row height for a tableview controller with varying image aspect ratios?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, autolayout, tableview

Currently I'm working on a media feed that may contain images in varying aspect ratios. Each image is to be scaled to the same width on the screen and the height will be adjusted according to the same ratio.

My tableViewController is using automatic dimensions. Each image is scaled to the correct width and height then a new image is created which is fed into its corresponding tableViewCell.

However, when the width and height is set programmatically (via auto dimension and the scaled image), I find a strange bug where I have to scroll around to get the image to display. (Video below). It's not until I use heightForRowAt and use a constant value where the aspect ratio is not preserved that the images display at the apps launch.

I'd love to be able to display these images in their correct aspect ratio. Any help is definitely appreciated.
Thanks!

**First Image: auto dimension**

***Images display after scrolling action (maybe a bug)***

[image]

**Second Image: height for row at**

[image]

**TableVC cell class**

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

class UserPostCell: UITableViewCell {

    // MARK: - Outlets

    @IBOutlet private weak var userProfileBtn: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet private weak var likeBtn: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet private weak var captionTxtField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var postImage: UIImageView!
    
    private(set) var height: CGFloat?
    
    
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
    }

    func configureCell(post: UserPost) {
        let gsReference = Storage.storage().reference(forURL: post.photoURL)
        
        var image: UIImage?
        
        gsReference.getData(maxSize: 1 * 1024 * 1024) { data, error in
            if let error = error {
                debugPrint("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            } else {
                
                image = UIImage(data: data!)
                
                //let h = image!.size.height
                let w = image!.size.width
                let wRatio = self.frame.size.width / w
                
                //create new image at correct scale
                let newImage = UIImage(data: data!, scale: 1 / wRatio)
                
                self.postImage.frame.size.height = newImage!.size.height
                
                self.postImage.image = newImage
                self.userProfileBtn.setTitle(post.username, for: .normal)
                self.captionTxtField.text = post.caption
            }
        }
    }
    
}
```

**View Controller**

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

class MainVC: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    
    
    // MARK: - Outlets
    @IBOutlet private weak var tableView: UITableView!
    
    // MARK: - Variables
    private var userPosts = [UserPost]()
    private var postsCollectionRef: CollectionReference!
    private var usersCollectionRef: CollectionReference!
    private var handle: AuthStateDidChangeListenerHandle?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
        tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 450
        
        postsCollectionRef = Firestore.firestore().collection(POSTS_REF)
        usersCollectionRef = Firestore.firestore().collection(USERS_REF)
        loadPosts()
    }
    
    func loadPosts() {
        
        var username: String?
        var profileURL: String?
        //var photoURL: String?
        var uid: String?
        
        //retrieve posts from database
        postsCollectionRef.getDocuments { snapshot, error in
            if let err = error {
                debugPrint(err.localizedDescription)
            } else {
                guard let snap = snapshot else { return }
                for d in snap.documents {
                    let data = d.data()
                    
                    uid = data[USER_ID] as? String ?? ""
                    //retrieve info about author of each post
                    let userDocRef = self.usersCollectionRef.document(uid!)
                    
                    //retrieve user info for each post
                    userDocRef.getDocument { document, error in
                        if let document = document, document.exists {
                            let dat = document.data()
                            //user data (dat)
                            username = dat![USERNAME] as? String ?? "Anonymous"
                            profileURL = dat![PROFILE_IMAGE] as? String ?? ""
                            // dat vs data fix this ^^^
                            
                            //post data (data)
                            let photoURL = data[PHOTO_URL] as? String ?? ""
                            let caption = data[CAPTION] as? String ?? ""
                            let numComments = data[NUM_COMMENTS] as? Int ?? 0
                            let numLikes = data[NUM_LIKES] as? Int ?? 0
                            
                            let timestamp = data[TIME_STAMP] as? Date ?? Date()
                            let documentId = d.documentID
                            print("photolink: \(photoURL)")
                            print("caption:  \(caption)")
                            let newPost = UserPost(name: username!, timestamp: timestamp, caption: caption, numLikes: numLikes, numComments: numComments, documentId: documentId, UID: uid!, profile: profileURL!, photo: photoURL)
                            self.userPosts.append(newPost)
                            self.tableView.reloadData()
                        } else {
                            print("This user document does not exist")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        //check if the user is logged in or not
        handle = Auth.auth().addStateDidChangeListener({ (auth, user) in
            if user == nil {
                let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
                let loginVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(identifier: "loginVC")
                self.present(loginVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
            } else {
                //self.loadPosts()
                // set listener
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        })
    }
    
    @IBAction func logoutBtnTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        let firebaseAuth = Auth.auth()
        do {
            try firebaseAuth.signOut()
        } catch let signoutError as NSError {
            debugPrint("Error signing out: \(signoutError)")
        }
    }
    
    @IBAction func reload(_ sender: Any) {
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return userPosts.count
    }
    
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "userPostCell", for: indexPath) as? UserPostCell{
            cell.configureCell(post: userPosts[indexPath.row])
            return cell
        } else {
            return UITableViewCell()
        }
    }
    
}
```

Comment: is second screenshot your requirement ? why are you manipulating the UIImage , you need to provide proper constraints to UIImageview (set aspect ration constraint there)

Comment: I'm retrieving the images from google firebase at a higher resolution @dip. To display correctly in the table view, I have to scale the width and height. Also, the second image is with the hard coded height on the cell. However, I wanted to use automatic dimensions.

Comment: what constraints are you given for the image try giving proper aspect ratio constraints and feel free to use some image caching libraries , prefetchDataSource

Comment: you can directly set the row height using tableview delegate method(heightForRowAtIndexPath) but if you use that there is some chances for scrolling issues(if you have huge amount of data), better you use fixed height and aspect ration constraints

Comment: This is because the image is loaded after the table view determines the height of each cell. Once an image is loaded you need to call tableView.beginUpdates() and tableView.endUpdates() to refresh the height. Also scroll to top with animated false, if needed.

Comment: the best practice is your server needs to return the image URL and size, so you can update image size(auto-layout or manual layout) quickly to avoid scrollview calculate content size  frequently and bugly

Answer (score 0):

The reason of this your cell is already created before UIImage loads up.
Best way to prevent this, give one of the constraints of the imageView.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).